# Bootcamp Windows 8.1 keymap

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, windows

Case:
I just received a MBP 13" Haswell Retina and installed Windows 8.1 with Bootcamp 5.0.5033 drivers.

Problem:
The Danish and Danish (Apple) keyboard layouts have two keys swapped: $ and <

How can I swap these back to their correct function?

Comment: Anyone who has this issue should give feedback on it at the apple website. It is so easy for them to fix - we shouldn't have to create layouts ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug with Win7 as well.
A bit of a show stopper for a developer...

If it's still a problem, then perhaps this can help:

I used [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=22339) to load the original 'Dansk (Apple)' layout, and alter the keys. It's pretty straight forward (load the keymap you want to alter, and when all done (remember shift+*keys*) click 'Project' => 'Build DLL and Setup Package'. Then install the new keyboard, and switch to it under 'Region and Language'). If it's fixed at some point you can just switch back to the original.

*BTW: The keys will look like they are in the right spots in Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator, even though they aren't.*

If Win7 and Win8 uses the same layouts, you can try the one I made. Download it [here](http://lalleland.dk/tmp/dansk-apple-fixed.zip). Happy new year!

Comment: This was the solution I ended up with.

Comment: Thanks for this, it fixed my da-DK layout problem as well!

Answer (score 0):

Although I think this is a bug in the driver pack, this is an issue you will have to solve in the Windows world.

You are running Windows and the keyboard is interpreted with a different layout than it actually has. Essentially you want to swap two keys in Windows. A short Google gave me several hits. Personally I always like LifeHacker: http://lifehacker.com/5883003/the-best-key-remapper-for-windows

Comment: I tried SharpKeys and KeyTweak but I couldn't get it to work properly. After uninstalling those it worked normally (confusing).